# How to navigate between two agents in anylogic

Tags: java, anylogic

I have a main agent and another agent. I have a view area in the other agent and when I run the simulation, I want to be able to swap between both agents. What do I write to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your actual setup. Please first study "[where am I and how do I get to](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fcode%2FAccess.html&resultof=%22%77%68%65%72%65%22%20%22%61%6D%22%20%22%69%22%20)" in the help. Once you understand these principles, you can use the `myViewArea.navigateTo()` function.

Also check (literally all!) example models. Their navigation is doing the same.